# 404 (Not Found) for CSS files

Tags: django, npm, leaflet, django-staticfiles

I am running a django app and I want to import a third-party stylesheet from my node_modules. But my django app is looking in the wrong directory and throws a 404 and I don't understand why.

My structure of the static files:

```
static
├── src
│   |
│   │   
│   ├── outputs
│   │   ├── example.css
│   │   ├── ..
│   │   ├── ..
│   │   ├── ..
│   │   └── ..
```

In my `example.css` I do the following:

```
@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

This should import my leaflet CSS - the `~` represents the path to the node modules- which is in my node_modules directory in my root directory (I also tried the absolute path to node_modules and the same error occurs).

I added the node_nodules to the STATIC_DIRS in the django config and my static file settings look like so:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "myproject/static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "node_modules"),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)
```

With this setting django should look into `node_modules` for the static files too.

Now, with the above settings, when I include my `example.css` into the head of my template I get the following error:

> GET http://localhost:8000/static/src/outputs/~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So obviously my app looks in the wrong directory, since it should look in `node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css`. I don't know where to tweak the settings to get this right. I could imagine that the problem is maybe that I don't have a `STATIC_ROOT` but a `STATIC_URL` set to `static`? Apart from that I'm a bit lost. Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Added the static root, but still no success

Comment: did you execute `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, should I? If I import the leaflet CSS into my CSS shouldn't it just take the CSS from there? When I run `collectstatic` it also imports all the node modules into the static folder

Comment: when staticfiles are served - the path of the target staticfile (in filesystem)  equals to URL path to that file. Thus such thing as `outputs/~leaflet` cannot be resolved. But what `collectstatic` does - it collects all dependencies into the target folder to be able to serve it. So my assumption that it may help

Comment: Thank you, I will try and report if it worked! Maybe you can help me understand this though: If instead of the CSS file in a JS file I do for example `import "leaflet";` then it imports the JavaScript without any problems from the `node_modules` without running `collectstatic`. But for the CSS it does not work that way, which strikes me as odd, since the JS files should behave similar as they are also static files....

Comment: I am not an expert in that field but can assume that it's because of different import mechanism between `css` and `js`.  `import` in `js` works because there is `export` in other file. I.e. other file available in that namespace and served separately. And in `css` this dependency resolved in more "direct" way - to serve it just tries to get the given path relative to the particular file

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552207/how-to-use-node-modules-with-django

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure

```
@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

Shouldn`t be

```
@import "~/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately also with the slash the CSS is not being found...

Comment: ok... whats the path present now in the error log? has it changed?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to include a `/` so that it reads as:

```
@import "~/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

Generally `~/` means to start from the home dir. `~` is a shortcut for the home directory

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately also with the slash the CSS is not being found...